# how to remove index.php?action=show&id=1234 from url on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My URL is localhost/merge/Clients/index.php?action=show&id=12 ..
 all i want to make it like localhost/merge/Clients

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Clients/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing to `RewriteBase /merge/Clients/`

Comment: it does not work for me .. {REQUEST_FILENAME} must be replace with what equivalent in my website and if that true .. what can i put between { } as REQUEST_FILENAME